# How to get rid of these apparently superfluous `undefined`s?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, haskell-lens

I'm using GHC 9.2.2 and playing with [`OverloadedRecordDot`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/overloaded_record_dot.html#extension-OverloadedRecordDot) and [generic-lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-lens). As an experiment, I want to use the overloaded dot as a "frontend" to the generic-lens functionality (including type-changing update).

I have these auxiliary definitions:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedRecordDot #-}
import Control.Lens ( (&), (.~), Lens )
import Data.Generics.Product.Fields qualified as G
import GHC.Records (HasField (..))
import GHC.TypeLits (Symbol)
import GHC.Generics (Generic)

-- Basically a 'Control.Lens.Reified.ReifiedLens'.
newtype Lensy s t a b = Lensy (Lens s t a b)

pry :: Lensy s t a b -> Lens s t a b
pry (Lensy l) = l

-- Just a dummy starting point for applying the overloaded dot.
data The s t = The
the :: s -> t -> The s t -- the parameters are just to guide type inference
the s t = The

-- This GHC.Records.HasField instance produces lenses, not values.
-- It piggybacks on Data.Generics.Product.Fields.HasField.
instance G.HasField (field :: Symbol) s t a b 
    => HasField field (The s t) (Lensy s t a b) where
    getField _ = Lensy (G.field @field)
```

And this example datatype taken from [`Data.Generics.Product.Fields`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-lens-2.2.1.0/docs/Data-Generics-Product-Fields.html):

```hs
data Human a
  = Human
    { name    :: String
    , address :: String
    , other   :: a
    }
  | HumanNoAddress
    { name    :: String
    , other   :: a
    }
  deriving (Generic, Show)

human :: Human Bool
human = Human { name = "Tunyasz", address = "London", other = False }
```

Putting my helpers to work, this compiles (don't mind the awful verbosity):

```
human' :: Human Int
human' = human & pry (the human human').other .~ (42 :: Int)
```

Passing `undefined`s as arguments to the `the` also compiles:

```
human' :: Human Int
human' = human & pry (the undefined undefined).other .~ (42 :: Int)
```

Ok, they seem to be unnecessary. Let's get rid of those parameters to `the`, then:

```hs
-- Just a dummy starting point for applying the overloaded dot.
data The s t = The
the :: The s t 
the = The

human' :: Human Int
human' = human & pry the.other .~ (42 :: Int)
```

Alas, this doesn't compile:

```
* Ambiguous type variables `s0', `t0',
                           `a0' arising from selecting the field `other'
  prevents the constraint `(HasField
                              "other"
                              (The s0 t0)
                              (Lensy (Human Bool) (Human Int) a0 Int))' from being solved.
```

How to make the parameterless version of `the` compile?

Answer (score 5):

Unwitting kind polymorphism strikes again.

```hs
ghci> :t the
the :: forall {k1} {k2} (s :: k1) (t :: k2). The s t
```

It was sufficient to add a kind signature to `The`:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
import Data.Kind ( Type )
type The :: Type -> Type -> Type
data The s t = The
```

And the signature of `the` becomes:

```
ghci> :t the
the :: forall s t. The s t
```

Comment: Also note that this is due to `PolyKinds` which is now on by default in GHC 9.2 as part of `GHC2021`.